# permission Denied Error : can't open 'etc/debian_version'

Tags: 20.04, mysql-workbench

Im a student and newbie with Ubuntu.
Im using Ubuntu 20.04.
in my current project im using Workbench for database, but im having this error (permission Denied Error : can't open 'etc/debian_version'), could anyone please help me!!

Comment: I believe it is /etc/debian_version. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please provide proper details. What are you trying to do and what exact error did you get ?

Comment: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld will help you explore your problem.

Comment: Im trying to connect to the database of a project that i cloned in localhost, using Workbench it prompt to me "Could not acquire management access for administration PermissionDeniedError: Can't open file '/etc/debian_version' "

Comment: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
$ cat /etc/debian_version
bullseye/sid

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a container (Docker) use the IP generated in the docker.

You can view with `docker inspect (Container ID)`. If not, change the file permission with `chmod`.